# Check Number sequence

Tags: c++

You are given S a sequence of n integers i.e. S = s1, s2, ..., sn. Compute if it is possible to split S into two parts : s1, s2, ..., si and si+1, si+2, ….., sn (0 <= i <= n) in such a way that the first part is strictly decreasing while the second is strictly increasing one.
Note : We say that x is strictly larger than y when x > y.
So, a strictly increasing sequence can be 1 4 8. However, 1 4 4 is NOT a strictly increasing sequence.

That is, in the sequence if numbers are decreasing, they can start increase at one point. And once number starts increasing, they cannot decrease at any point further.
Sequence made up of only increasing numbers or only decreasing numbers is a valid sequence. So in both the cases, print true.

You just need to print true/false. No need to split the sequence.

Input format :

Line 1 : Integer 'n'
Line 2 and Onwards : 'n' integers on 'n' lines(single integer on each line)

Output Format :

"true" or "false" (without quotes)

Constraints :

1 <= n <= 10^7

Sample Input 1 :

```
5
9
8
4
5
6
```

Sample Output 1 :

```
true
```

Sample Input 2 :

```
3
1
2
3
```

Sample Output 2 :

```
true
```

Sample Input 3 :

```
3
8
7
7
```

Sample Output 3 :

```
false
```

Explanation for Sample Format 3 :

8 7 7 is not strictly decreasing, so output is false.

Sample Input 4 :

```
6
8
7
6
5
8
2
```

Sample Output 4 :

```
false
```

Explanation for Sample Input 4 :

The series is :
8 7 6 5 8 2
It is strictly decreasing first (8 7 6 5). Then it's strictly increasing (5 8). But then it starts strictly decreasing again (8 2). Therefore, the output for this test case is 'false'

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int p;
    cin >> p;
    bool isDec = true;
    int i = 1,c;
    while(i <= n - 1){
        cin >> c;
        
        if(c > p){
            if(isDec == true){
            isDec = false;
            }
            isDec = true;
            p = c; 
        } else if(c < p){
            if(isDec == false){
            isDec = false;
            }
            isDec  = true;
            p = c;
        } else {
            isDec = false;
            break;
        }
        
        i++;
    }
    
    if(isDec){
    cout << "true" << endl;
    } else{
        cout << "false" << endl;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code? It failed for last test case.

Comment: How did it fail? Which test case?? What output did you get?

Comment: i got true but output should be false      6
8
7
6
5
8
2

Comment: Add that to your question

Comment: Debug your code and check what happens at `break;`.

Comment: The logic for (c>p) is identical to the logic for (c<p)

Comment: @Bhuvnesh Bansal  Could you elaborate why this sequence 5
9
8
4
5
6 yields true while this sequence 3
8
7
7 yields false.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  because in last two digits are equal(7 = 7) and above ques. says it's false

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int current_term;
    cin>>current_term;
    bool isDecreasing = true,is_valid_sequence_yet=true;
    int i=2;// first term of sequence has already been taken
    while(i<=n){
        int next_term;
        cin>>next_term;
        if(is_valid_sequence_yet && isDecreasing && current_term>next_term){
            current_term=next_term;
            isDecreasing=true;
        }else if(is_valid_sequence_yet && current_term < next_term){
            current_term=next_term;
            isDecreasing = false;
        }else{
            is_valid_sequence_yet=false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(is_valid_sequence_yet){
        cout << "true" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "false" <<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class test{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=s.nextInt();
int arr[]=new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    arr[i]=s.nextInt();
}
boolean flag=true;
for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++){
   if((arr[i]<arr[i+1])&& arr[i+1]>arr[i+2])){
       flag=false;
         break;
      }
 }
 System.out.print(flag);
 }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
int num , temp = 1 , i =1  ;
cin>>num;
bool Isdec = true;
int Previes_num , current_num;
cin>>Previes_num;

  while(i <= num-1){
      
      cin>>current_num;
      
    if(Previes_num > current_num){
          if(Isdec){
              Isdec = true ;
            temp++;
          }
        else{
            cout<<"false";
            return 0;
        }
    }    
      
    else if(current_num > Previes_num){
          if(Isdec){
              Isdec = false ;
          }
        
    }
     else{
         cout<<"false";
         return 0 ;
     } 
      ++i;
      Previes_num=current_num;
      
  }
    if(temp==num){
        cout<<"true";
    }
    else if(Isdec == 0){
        cout<<"true" ;
    }
    
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;

     int t1,t2; // two consecutive terms

     cin >> t1;
     cout << endl;

     bool changed=false; // this will turn true once the series has switched to increasing mode
     bool result=true; // we will change it to flase if any condition is voilated 

     for(int i=2;i<=n;i++) { // i=2 since we already took one input

         cin >> t2;
         cout << endl;

         if (t1>t2) {
             if (changed == true) {//we are in the increasing part 
                 result = false; //since now the terms are decreasing but we are in incresaing part the series is no longer valid
             }
         }

         else if (t1<t2) {
             if ( changed == false) { 
                 changed = true;  // the series has now changed to increasing series if it wasn't before
             }
         }

         else  {
             result = false; // if tow terms are equal the result is automatically false
         }
         t1=t2; // replacing the terms to get new input
     }
     if (result) cout << "true"; // if we dont do this we get 0,1 as output
     else cout << "false";

}
```

We need to set two bools as shown. Once our series changes from decreasing to increasing we will set `change` to `true`.

If we already have `change` set to `true` but our series changes again from decreasing to increasing we will set `result` bool to false.

In the end we can output `result` to get our required answer.

In case we get two consecutive terms equal we straightaway set `result` to `false` as it directly violates our condition of strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

We will not use break anywhere because user is expected to give all the inputs and then result is displayed.

As for debugging your code, you need to change your approach. Also, what did you even intend to accomplish by this :

```
            if(isDec == false){
            isDec = false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n,p,i,c,dec,inc;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> p;
    bool is = true;
    i = 1;
    dec=0;
    inc=0;
    while(i <= n - 1){
        cin >> c;
        
        if(c > p){
            inc=1;
            p = c; 
            is=true;
        } 
        else if(c < p){
            if(inc==1){
                is=false;
                break;
            }
            is=true;
            dec=1;
            p = c;
        } 
        else {
            is = false;
            break;
        }
        
        i++;
    }
    if(is){
        cout << "true" << endl;
    } else{
        cout << "false" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details about your code.